# Как правильно разбить строку по определенному символу

Tags: php

Имеется строка вида: `192.168.0.1@User;p@ssword`. 
Мне нужно положить в массив отдельно 192.168.0.1, User и p@ssword, чтобы пользоваться этими данными по отдельности. 
Дело в том, что, если запись будет в таком виде - `192.168.0.1@User;password`, то мне удается получить значения через этот код:

```
$data = explode("@", "192.168.0.1@User;password");
$data2= explode(";", $data[1]);
```

В итоге я пользуюсь всеми тремя значениями:

```
$data[0] (192.168.0.1)
$data2[0] (User)
$data2[1] (password)
```

Получается, что проблема возникает, когда в строке два символа - @.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php): `preg_split('/[@;]/', $str, 3)`

Comment: @vp_arth, Благодарю, работает! :)

Comment: Кстати, у `explode` тоже есть третий аргумент. В вашем варианте: `explode('@', $str, 2)`

Comment: или еще лучше сразу `list($ip, $user, $pwd) = preg_split(...)`  ;

Comment: эм-м-м, а как будет в случае ipv6 ?

Answer (score 1):

вот так можно

```
$data = explode("@", "192.168.0.1@User;p@ssword", 2);
$user = explode(';', $data[1], 2);
var_dump($data, $user);
```

Вот результат https://3v4l.org/8QBr9

Используется параметр limit http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php